# Rails child find by id returns the parent class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, parent-child

I have parent class called Field

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And a child class called ProfileField

```
class ProfileField < Field
    def self.base_class ; self ; end
    def self.use_base_class; ProfileField; end
    self.table_name = "fields"

    def field_type
     return "profile_field"
    end
end
```

I have a database table "fields" and there is column called field_type. 
I created a Field object using Field.create with null in the field_type column.
I also created a ProfileField object using ProfileField.create and gave a the type "profile_field".

let's say the id for Field object (parent class) is 10 and the child Object ProfileFiled id is 11.
When I do ProfileField.find(10) i will get a ProfileField object back. I will also get a Profile Object back when I do Profile.find(10).
Shouldn't I not get anything when I do ProfileField.find(10) since the Object with id 10 was a Profile Object and not a ProfileField Object?

Comment: Active record translates your requests/commands into sql. So, if you have the same table for Field and ProfileField, find by id should return results for both classes. Maybe you should dedicate a boolean field to distinguishing between these two...

Comment: thank you. I found the answer. I need a type column my fields table that would automatically get populated with Object type when creating a new Object.

Comment: Same logic, different action. Mine was just an idea, not the only way to do it. It's good that you put down your own practices. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the code you shared, you seem to implement Single Table Inheritance by hand. However, Rails (or rather Active Record) doesn't know about your intention. All it knows is that two classes use the same table. You could simply put "monkey" or any other arbitrary value in your `field_type` column and AR wouldn't know it should actually determine the class to be used.

The only proper indication for STI is a table column named `type`. This is a general convention - sort of a reserved column name only for this purpose.

Rails/AR will then handle the type column all by itself. In fact, you probably should not tinker with it. Whenever you select a record from the table, you will get the object type according to the type column as you expected with your implementation.

See here for more info on STI and its implementation and usage:

http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/